# How to handle rotation by x, y position and dynamic angle using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rotation

I have content which might have a dynamic angle(Degree of rotation will be managed by admin panel which starts from 0 and end at 360 degrees).

```
function animateScroll(){
    var deg = 45;
    var offset = (deg >= 90) ? $('.parent').height() : $('.parent').width();
    $( ".block" ).each(function () {this.offsetX = offset }).animate({
        offsetX: '-'+$('.block').width()
        }, {
        duration: 10000,
        step: function (now, fx) { //console.log(now)
         var scaleVal =parseInt( now);
         scaleVal += 10;
        $(this).css('transform','rotate('+deg+'deg) translateX('+scaleVal+'px) translateY(0px)'); 
        },
        complete: function () {//console.log('in complate')
             return animateScroll();
         },
        easing: 'linear'
        });
}
animateScroll();
```

But it is not working properly at a position in different degree:

https://jsfiddle.net/gx1srvsg/2/

see one more degree 135

https://jsfiddle.net/gx1srvsg/7/

See in this fiddle, rotated text is not at 45deg. It must rotate from top left position which will be dynamic.

How to do it?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem correctly but I think you can fix it by setting the elements anchor point for transform (eg: `transform-origin:left top;`) because by default it is set to the center of the element.

Comment: transform-origin:left top; is not working for all degrees